# What is the best protocol to transfer large files over WAN?

Tags: debian, ftp, sftp

I am running a Debian 8 machine that has 50mb/s download and 5mb/s upload(on a good day) connection and I need to remotely upload large video files upwards of 15gb over a Wide Area Network. I am not sure what file transfer protocol would be the fastest and secure. ie SFTP, FTP, FTPS, etc.

Comment: IMHO you should look into scp.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of files that you want to upload.

If they are databases or non-compressed dumps, scp is more efficient, if they are compressed, FTP is more eficient, scp more secure.

Often in my internal network I go commando and do tar's on top of netcat's.

If the contents are incremental and always the same files and do not change much over time, a good idea is doing an rsync on top of ssh.